# Which URLs are valid for map/reduce queries in CouchDB?

Tags: javascript, curl, couchdb

I have this simple map/reduce function in my CouchDB. This one maps

```
function(doc) {
  emit(doc.Retweeted_user, 1);
  emit(doc.User, 1);
}
```

And this one reduces

```
function( keys,values ) {
  return sum( values );
}
```

It's saved as users/howmany. I'm using this for making the query

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:5984/test20n/_design/users/_view/how_many'
```

But this replies

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

And if I try other things, like,

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:5984/test20n/_design/users/_view/how_many?group="true"'
```

I get exactly the same answer. What kind of URL magic is needed here?

This happened for version 0.10.0, the one that gets installed in Ubuntu 10.04. I have tried now with 1.0.1, And it works perfectly, so maybe it was an error that was fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you saved it as count/howmany but the word 'count' appears nowhere in your url, so you should be getting a 404. You might mean;

```
curl 'http://localhost:5984/test20n/_design/count/_view/how_many'
```

or

```
curl 'http://localhost:5984/test20n/_design/users/_view/count%2fhow_many'
```

depending on whether 'count' was your design document name or part of the view name.

As to why you get that strange curl error, I can't explain it, but if you run the following command and paste the full results (omitting any Authorization header), I can help;

```
curl -sv 'http://localhost:5984/test20n/_design/users/_view/how_many'
```

http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API

Comment: I have tried what you say, and here's the answer `curl -sv 'http://localhost:5984/test20n/_design/users/_view/how_many'
* About to connect() to localhost port 5984 (#0)
*   Trying ::1... Conexión rehusada
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 5984 (#0)
> GET /test20n/_design/users/_view/how_many HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (i486-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 OpenSSL/0.9.8k zlib/1.2.3.3 libidn/1.15
> Host: localhost:5984
> Accept: */*
> 
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection #0
`